# Conditionally edit column values for n number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change the values of a given column for the first 4 rows that appear for a specific boxer in my dataset

This is a sample of my data

```
name               clean_outcome     
Tyson Fury             an               
Other Boxer            win
Tyson Fury             an 
Other Boxer            win
Tyson Fury
Tyson Fury 
Tyson Fury
Other Boxer
Tyson Fury
```

...

This is what I have tried:

```
fully_merged[fully_merged.name == 'Tyson Fury'].iloc[0:4]['clean_outcome'] = 'Win Other'
```

The ideal output would be this:

```
name               clean_outcome     
Tyson Fury             Win Other               
Tyson Fury             Win Other 
Tyson Fury             Win Other
Tyson Fury             Win Other
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use .loc with boolean indexing and column filtering,

```
df.loc[((df['name'] == 'Tyson Fury').cumsum() <= 4) & 
        (df['name'] == 'Tyson Fury'), 
       'clean_outcome'] = 'Win Other'
```

Output:

```
          name clean_outcome
0   Tyson Fury     Win Other
1  Other Boxer           win
2   Tyson Fury     Win Other
3  Other Boxer           win
4   Tyson Fury     Win Other
5   Tyson Fury     Win Other
6   Tyson Fury          None
7  Other Boxer          None
8   Tyson Fury          None
```

Comment: Hmm I think I interpreted this wrong. I selected the first 4 rows rather than the first 4 in which the name is Tyson. This looks good. Only detail is I'd perhaps compute this once separately `df['name'] == 'Tyson Fury')`